# How to filter a labelled tibble in R

Tags: r, labelled

I want to filter `df` tibble using the variable `s2` with values 2 and 3. I get a new tibble `df2` that keeps showing also the value 1 of s2.

How can I create a new tibble with only the filtered values of `df`?

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(labelled)

df <- tibble(s1 = c("M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F"),
             s2 = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3)) %>% 
  set_variable_labels(s1 = "Sex", s2 = "Question") %>%
  set_value_labels(s1 = c(Male = "M", Female = "F"), s2 = c(Yes = 1, No = 2, DK =3))

df2 <- df %>% filter(s2 %in% c("2", "3"))

df2$s2
#> <labelled<double>[2]>: Question
#> [1] 2 3
#> 
#> Labels:
#>  value label
#>      1   Yes
#>      2    No
#>      3    DK
Created on 2022-10-12 with reprex v2.0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new tibble `df2` does only contain the filtered values. In your results it shows

```
#> [1] 2 3
```

which are the filtered results you want.

The extra detail printed are attributes associated with the data. They show the defined labels for `s2` but the data you have filtered does not have every label here.

```
#> Labels:
#>  value label
#>      1   Yes
#>      2    No
#>      3    DK
```

**Edit based on update from OP:**

To filter the label attributes based on the filtered data, I think you need

```
df2 <- df %>% filter(s2 %in% c("2", "3")) %>% drop_unused_value_labels()

df2$s2
#> <labelled<double>[2]>: Question
#> [1] 2 3
#> 
#> Labels:
#>  value label
#>      2    No
#>      3    DK
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew that. The problem is that when I want for example to do a crosstab like this: `library(sjmisc) flat_table(df2, s1, s2)` I see that label 'Yes' with zeros. Imagine that you begin with 100 countries and want only to see 3...

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully that helps.